# Bad performance score in lighthouse on almost empty page in Next.js

Tags: performance, next.js, lighthouse

I'm currently developing locally, using `npm run dev` in Next.js

I tested my website, and got 40 score in Performance

[image]

I have tried using lighthouse in secret mode, however it was same.

Also, every other pages have similar score in performance, and I can't figure out why they are.

[image]

As you see, Diagnostics shows no special thing.

What am I missing?

Comment: That's expected as you're testing against the app in development mode. Try running the app in production mode (next build && next start) in incognito mode instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as it is known, in a local environment you don't get to make use of Next's static generations, ISR, and other pre-rendering features. That is because Next is regenerating and reloading every script needed for rendering each page at every refresh, making it so it's actually easier to debug changes in advanced functions like `getStaticPaths()`, `getStaticProps()` etc.

If you do want to test and gather actual analytics data, deploy your app for free to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/), and measure performance on the domains they provide you. You can follow the instructions for deploying your Next.js app on Vercel [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-nextjs-app).

Comment: Thank you. I'll check my performance once again after deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting poor score simply because your are performing lighthouse test on development using `npm run dev`.

First build by `npm run build` then start a production server using `npm run start` then check your lighthouse score.